# Set a featured image as a replacement to the header image

Tags: theme-development, themes, post-thumbnails, header-image

I am setting a header image as a background image to the `.blog__header` block via inline styles in functions.php:

```
$header_image = get_header_image();

if ( $header_image ) {
    $header_image_css = "
            .blog__header {
                    background-image: url({$header_image});
            }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-styles', $header_image_css );
}
```

now I want to replace this header image with a featured image if set:

```
$header_image = get_header_image();

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail('full');
}

if ( $header_image ) {
    $header_image_css = "
            .blog__header {
                    background-image: url({$header_image});
            }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-styles', $header_image_css );
} elseif ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $post_thumbnail_css = "
            .blog__header {
                    background-image: url({$post_thumbnail});
            }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-styles', $post_thumbnail_css );
}
```

however it doesn't work, probaly because I have not set the post ID. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention or shown in the code to which hook are you hooking the above code to, but here's what I think should work. NOT TESTED

```
global $post;
$header_image = '';

// featured image is first priority, right?
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
    $header_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' );
} elseif ( !empty( get_header_image() ) ) {
    $header_image = get_header_image();
}

$header_image_css = ".blog__header { background-image: url({$header_image}); }";
wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-styles', $header_image_css );
```

Comment: Thanks, Junaid! I am using the following hook: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'touche_inline_styles' );`. I will test your code and get back to you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have added some lines in hero-header.php:

old code:

```
if ( get_header_image() ) {
?>
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( 'site-hero-header-image site-hero-header-image--' . Oceanly\Helpers::hero_header_bg_position() . ' site-hero-header-image--size-' . Oceanly\Helpers::hero_header_bg_size() . $oceanly_hero_header_bg_fixed_class ); ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php header_image(); ?>);"></div>
<?php
```

}

with new code added:

```
    if ( get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID , 'full') ) {
    ?>
    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( 'site-hero-header-image site-hero-header-image--' . Oceanly\Helpers::hero_header_bg_position() . ' site-hero-header-image--size-' . Oceanly\Helpers::hero_header_bg_size() . $oceanly_hero_header_bg_fixed_class ); ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);"></div>
    <?php
} elseif ( get_header_image() ) {
    ?>
    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( 'site-hero-header-image site-hero-header-image--' . Oceanly\Helpers::hero_header_bg_position() . ' site-hero-header-image--size-' . Oceanly\Helpers::hero_header_bg_size() . $oceanly_hero_header_bg_fixed_class ); ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php header_image(); ?>);"></div>
    <?php
}
```